# Why do I get FileNotFoundException when I create and try to write to file on Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-emulator, filenotfoundexception

First off, I am not trying to write to the SDCard. I want to write some information to a file that persists between uses of the app. It is essentially a file to hold favorites of the particular user. Here is what the code looks like:

```
try {
            File file = new File("favorites.txt");

            if (file.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File does exist.");
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "File does not exist.");
                return favDests;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When running this code, we always get the "File does not exist." message in our DDMS log.

We have also tried the following code to no avail:

```
try {
            File file = new File(GoLincoln.FAV_DEST_FILE);

            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is this second portion of code that results in the FileNotFoundException.

I have read multiple tutorials on writing and reading files on Android and I believe I am following them pretty closely, so I am not sure why this code doesn't work successfully. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you ever written to the file ? New File() does not create any file until you open an OutpuStream and write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `File` class directly. Use `Activity.getCacheDir()` to get the cache dir which is specific to your application. Then use `new File(cachedir, "filename.tmp")` to create the file.

Comment: Also look at the preferences classes in android. I think that might fit better for list of data.

Comment: Would it be better to use Activity.getFilesDir() rather than .getCacheDir()?

Comment: getFilesDir is the same as using openFileOutput. So it depends what you need it for. If its not really caching then getFilesDir might be better suited.

Comment: I want the file and the information stored in it to persist on the device between uses of the app. So if the person kills the app and opens it again, their favorites from previous uses should still exist. Will that allow me to do this?

Comment: Anyone like to weight on this last question?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences and SQLLite will both allow you to have persistent data without managing your own files.

To use shared preferences you grab it from your context, then you edit the values like so

```
mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("DatabaseNameWhateverYouWant", 0);
mySharedPreferences.getEditor().putString("MyPreferenceName", "Value").commit();
```

To get a preference out

```
mySharedPreferences.getString("MyPreferenceName", "DefaultValue");
```

This is really the simplest way to do basic preferences, much easier then doing a file. More then strings are supported, most basic data types are available to be added to the Preferences class.